# Disqus not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, disqus

I have tried to use Diqus comment system in my site using ajax to load the article and comments and i couldn't make it work.

I use jQuery and i load the whole article (comments included) with the action ".load".

I am using the code they provide in their site for this cases: 
http://docs.disqus.com/help/85/

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
});
```

I really don't know what i am doing bad. My code is this one:

```
$(".cargaAqui").load("http://"+ document.domain + "/myArticle"+id, function() {
DISQUS.reset({
reload: true,
config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "myArticle" + id;  
    this.page.url = 'http://' + document.domain +'/view-'+ id+'#!newthread';
}
 });
```

Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: A valuable tool for debugging javascript is the Firebug extension for Firefox. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yeah i have done it.  But i don't see where's the problem. I have followed everything they say in their site. Has anyone tried it with ajax?

Comment: OK, i asked one of the workers in there personally and i got an answer. Disqus doesn't support AJAX yet. Maybe soon.

Comment: @Steve - I'm having the same problems so on the disqus site they have this code but how can you make it work?? did u get any further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a basic template with working DISQUS 2012 comments loading with ajax via jquery-pjax.

DISQUS 2012 does not work with DISQUS.reset yet, but they're working on it.

<s>If you need DISQUS.reset to reload comments after ajax loading content, you'll need to turn off 2012 features in DISQUS admin.</s>

[UPDATE:] DISQUS.reset has since been implemented in DISQUS 2012, so the workaround above is not really necessary. However, push state combined with DISQUS.reset work really well together.

Comment: FYI your code has an element memory leak. You need to adjust the Disqus code so that you remove the old script elements as you navigate to each page. Its really easy to see it: open a firebug-like app and watch the disqus script tags accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adam. Disqus script tags accumulate. I did that :

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.removeChild(head.lastElementChild);
```

Put it just before the DISQUS function.

It works perfectly for me, because Disqus script tag is at the end of head. I run firebug again in Chrome, and Disqus script tags didn't accumulate any more.